# Error with my python script

Tags: python, fme-form

I am trying to write a string that will call for a error log.  Here is the error I am getting:

```
Python Exception <IOError>: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'C:<backslash>Users<backslash>Kyle<backslash>Documents<backslash>FRONTIER<backslash>Project1_varasett2frogs<solidus>V2Frogs_detaillog_20151110_142249916000.txt'
```

The FMEMacro DETAIL LOG is what is set to that filename.  I am not the greatest at python and having issues trying to figure out where i went wrong.

Programs I am using are FME and ArcMap 10.3

Here is the entire script:

```py
import fme
import sys
import fmeobjects
import datetime
import time


# Template Function interface:
def processFeature(feature):

    endstamp = datetime.datetime.now()
    endstamp = endstamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S.%f")
    dataset_list = feature.getAttribute('DATABASE_NAME').split(',')
    dataset_list = list(set(dataset_list))
    dataset_list.sort()
    dataset_list = ', '.join(dataset_list)

    # Read detail log and extract summary data
    with open(FME_MacroValues['DETAIL_LOG'], "r") as ins:
        delete_count = 0
        insert_count = 0
        update_count = 0
        redundant_count = 0
        error_count = 0
        action_list = []
        merged_list = []
        for line in ins:
            line_array = line.split(' :: ')
            line_action = line_array[3].replace('\n','')
            action_list.append(line_action)
            if line_action.upper() == 'delete':
                delete_count += 1
            elif line_action.upper() == 'insert':
                insert_count += 1
            elif line_action.upper() == 'update':
                update_count += 1
            elif line_action.upper() == 'redundant':
                redundant_count += 1
            elif line_action.upper() == 'error':
                error_count += 1

    # Create email body/summary (including location of detail log)
    email_body = "THIS IS A MOCK RUN - NO WRITERS HAVE BEEN ENABLED \n"
    email_body += "Start:\t" + FME_MacroValues['Time'] + "\n"
    email_body += "Finish:\t" + endstamp + "\n \n"
    email_body += "Inserted:\t" + str(insert_count) + "\n"
    email_body += "Updated:\t" + str(update_count) + "\n"
    email_body += "Deleted:\t" + str(delete_count) + "\n"
    email_body += "Redundant:\t" + str(redundant_count) + "\n"
    email_body += "Errors:\t\t" + str(error_count) + "\n \n"
    # Send email w/ detail log as attachment
    # Output attributes for debugging
    feature.setAttribute('body',email_body)
```

Comment: Did you paste the error correctly? If so, it looks like your filename is getting mangled...

Comment: I think so, its up top and I copied just like FME sent to me.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, FME uses an internal encoding system (we call it What Would Juan Do, as Juan is our XML expert).

I *think* what you need to do is apply the method decodeFromFMEParsableText. I'm not a programming expert, so I will give you the info I have and hope either it helps or someone here can assist.

I got this from the API documentation (see C:\apps\FME\fmeobjects\python\apidoc\Index.html)

---

Module fmeobjects :: Class FMESession

Method: decodeFromFMEParsableText(parsableText)

This method performs a modification of the unicode string from parsable FME encoded text back to a non-encoded form. For example, ' will be replaced with ';'. If the decoding fails for a particular character sequence, the resulting output will retain that character sequence.

Parameters:

```
    parsableText (string or unicode) - FME encoded text as a string or unicode.
```

Returns: unicode
    Non-encoded text as unicode.

---

My colleague tells me you'll want to do something like:

```
session = fmeobjects.FMESession()
decoded = session.decodeFromFMEParsableText(WWJDStringVAR)
```

So I'm guessing:

```
session = fmeobjects.FMESession()
decoded = session.decodeFromFMEParsableText(FME_MacroValues['DETAIL_LOG'])
with open(decoded, "r") as ins:
```

Answer (score 0):

`'C:<backslash>Users<backslash>Kyle<backslash>Documents<backslash>FRONTIER<backslash>Project1_varasett2frogs<solidus>V2Frogs_detaillog_20151110_142249916000.txt'` is invalid as a path. It appears that certain symbols are being replaced with words. I don't know anything about FMEMacro DETAIL LOGs, but as a work around you can try something like this:

```
pathName = FME_MacroValues['DETAIL_LOG']
fixedPathName = pathName.replace ("<backslash>", "\\").replace ("<solidus>", "-")
with open(fixedPathName, "r") as ins:
    ...
```

The code above replaces the words with their proper symbols. Add `.replace ()` as needed.